# tinymce is loading script from the cloud

Tags: javascript, tinymce

How to prevent tinymce loading things from the cloud, but instead loading them from the local path?

```
tinymce.init({
    selector:'textarea',theme: "modern",
    height: 400,
    document_base_url : "http://my_domain.com/",
    relative_urls : true,
external_plugins: {
    'responsivefilemanager': '/assets/js/plugins/responsivefilemanager/plugin.min.js',
    'filemanager': '/assets/js/plugins/filemanager/plugin.min.js',
},
etc...
```

but then in the console i see this:

https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/plugins/filemanager/dialog.php?editor=content